# Warning in ./libraries/classes/Util.php#1425 preg_replace(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I'm trying to build a site offline and had logged in with the intention of creating a child theme but a number of errors appeared.

I have tried adding the following line to the php.ini: "pcre.jit=0"

This is the error displayed:

> Warning in ./libraries/classes/Util.php#1425 preg_replace(): JIT
>   compilation failed: no more memory
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/classes/Util.php#1425: preg_replace( string '/\.?0+$/',
>   string '', string '48.0', ) ./libraries/classes/Util.php#1295:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Util::formatNumber( double 48.0, integer 5, integer 1,
>   boolean true, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Controllers/Database/DatabaseStructureController.php#1127:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Util::formatByteDown( double 48.0, integer 3, integer 1, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Controllers/Database/DatabaseStructureController.php#1006:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController->getValuesForInnodbTable(
>   array, integer 49152, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Controllers/Database/DatabaseStructureController.php#438:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController->getStuffForEngineTypeTable(
>   array, integer 0, integer 0, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Controllers/Database/DatabaseStructureController.php#195:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController->displayTableList()
>   ./db_structure.php#38:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController->indexAction()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MAMP you should find "$YourMampDir/php/etc/php.ini" file. Open it, and seek:

```
; Enables or disables JIT compilation of patterns. This requires the PCRE
; library to be compiled with JIT support.
; pcre.jit=1
```

you should edit it to:

```
; Enables or disables JIT compilation of patterns. This requires the PCRE
; library to be compiled with JIT support.
pcre.jit=0
```

Don't forget to reload your Apache Web Server. After that, the error should be gone.